# "simple" installer for a web application (IIS virtual app + sql server db setup)

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, installation

I need to create a web application installer.

Install Shield seems like overkill, is there something that can reliably install a web application (IIS setup + sql server db setup).

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CruiseControl.NET (http://sourceforge.net/projects/ccnet/) uses NullSoft's NSIS for this.   It does a good job and it's free.  The installer setup scripts, including the VBScript program that sets some of the website characteristics in IIS, are all in the source tree (http://ccnet.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ccnet/trunk/ccnet.nsi?view=log and http://ccnet.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ccnet/trunk/install).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [WIX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/overview.htm), [schema help](http://www.wixwiki.com/index.php?title=Wix_Schema),  it can do what you want and so much more ...

Answer (score 1):

InstallShield or one of its competitors is the simple solution anything else is going to require you to know way to much about msi(and that is a major headache).
I currently favor [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/) they have a free edition. I believe InstallSheild has a free version as well, I just don't like the InstallShield product any longer and it bothers me that their holding company practacly changes every year.

Answer (score 0):

I can only second [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System). Supports scripting and is easy to set-up.

Answer (score -1):

installshield is a good way to do this. handles sql server setup and iis config fairly well.

not cheap though I'm afraid but worth it for any type of install. wix might be an good option but how much time can you afford to spend on learning it rather than clicking some wizards in installshield.